# My full name in my passport is split on my US B1 visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

My Indian passport states that my given name is Mahesh Govindan and my surname is blank. However, the B1 visa stamped in my passport states that my given name is Mahesh and my surname is Govindan. The spelling of the split names is the same as the original name.

Will I face any problems when clearing immigration in the USA or during flight check-in due to this? Please advise.

Comment: Does the name in the visa match how you input the data in your application? What did you input for surname? Official advice if only one name is written in your passport, is to enter that as your “Surname.” https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/ds-160-faqs.html

Comment: were you able to get answer to your question? I have similar case and have the same concern as yours